# Python extracting excel files from multiple folders with dynamic name

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure, I want to be able to extract the Whse Summary Week x file from each folder and have something which is future proof. How should I do this?

[image]

Comment: [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) would work for you. `glob.glob("KPI/*/*/Whse Summary Week *")`/

Comment: @tdelaney that works thanks, but it is only returning some of the files

Comment: Maybe `glob.glob("KPI/**/Whse Summary Week*")`. The `**` means to search all subdirectories. Otherwise, see if there is something different about the skipped file names not accounted in the glob.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `pathlib` library which is built-in, no need for extra installations. The `pathlib` library provides the `Path` class for interacting with files in your machine.

Here is an example of a script that extracts the `'Whse Summary Week x'` files from each folder:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# define the base directory
# base_dir = 'KPI'
base_dir = './'

# define the file pattern
# NOTE: The prefix "**/" means "search recursively" in all subdirectories
file_pattern = '**/Whse Summary Week *.xlsx'
# Or, if you want to search for all Excel files, use this pattern:
# file_pattern = '**/*.xlsx'

# create a list of all files that match the pattern
list(Path(base_dir).glob(file_pattern))
# Returns:
#
# [PosixPath('Week 2 WE 10 July 22/Warehouse/Whse Summary Week 2.xlsx'),
# PosixPath('Week 3 WE 17 July 22/Warehouse/Whse Summary Week 3.xlsx'),
# PosixPath('Week 53&1 WE 03 July 22/Warehouse/Whse Summary Week 1.xlsx')]
```

### Making it future-proof

One way to make the above suggested implementation more "future-proof", would be to encapsulate the entire process into a function. In this new function, you could make `base_dir` and `file_pattern` input parameters, so that you can change it with time, if needed:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Union


def find_excel_files(
    base_dir: Union[str, Path] = './',
    file_pattern: str = '**/Whse Summary Week *.xlsx',
    return_type: type = str,
) -> Union[List[Path], List[str]]:
    """
    Find Excel files in a directory based on a pattern.

    This function searches for Excel files in a given directory and its
    subdirectories. The search is based on a file pattern.
    By default, it returns a list of strings representing the file paths,
    but this can be adjusted to return Path objects.

    Parameters
    ----------
    base_dir : Union[str, Path], optional
        The directory to search. It can be a string representing a
        path or a Path object. Default is the current directory.
    file_pattern : str, default='**/Whse Summary Week *.xlsx'
        The pattern to match the Excel files.
    return_type : type {str, pathlib.Path}, default=str
        The type of the elements in the returned list.
        It can be `str` or `Path`. Default is `str`.

    Returns
    -------
    Union[List[Path], List[str]]
        A list of file paths. The type of the elements is determined by the
        `return_type` parameter. If no match is found, then function
        returns an empty list

    Examples
    --------
    Find all Excel files in the current directory and its subdirectories:

    >>> find_excel_files()
    ['path/to/Whse Summary Week 1.xlsx', 'path/to/Whse Summary Week 2.xlsx']

    Find all Excel files in a specific directory and return `Path` objects:

    >>> find_excel_files(base_dir='/path/to/dir', return_type=Path)
    [Path('path/to/Whse Summary Week 1.xlsx'), Path('path/to/Whse Summary Week 2.xlsx')]

    Find all Excel files, including files ending with ".xlsm", ".xls" or ".xlsx":
    >>> find_excel_files(file_pattern="**/*.xl*")
    ['path/to/Whse Summary Week 1.xlsm', 'path/to/Whse Summary Week 2.xls']

    Notes
    -----
    Change `file_pattern` to `'**/*.xlsx'` to retrieve all Excel files inside
    `base_dir` and its subdirectories.
    """
    return list(map(return_type, Path(base_dir).glob(file_pattern)))


find_excel_files('KPI')
```